# Allowing a dash in this regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this Wordpress plugin called 'Easy contact form' which offers standard validation methods.

It uses the following regex for phone numbers:

```
/^(\+{0,1}\d{1,2})*\s*(\(?\d{3}\)?\s*)*\d{3}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}(-{0,1}|\s{0,1})\d{2}$/
```

Just now it allows the following formats (maybe more):

```
0612345678
+31612345678
```

But I want it to allow `+316-12345678` and `06-12345678` also ... Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried modifying the regex?

Comment: If you have only those 4 needs, your regex is vastly complex

Comment: Your phone numbers can have 10 or 11 digits, is that right ?

Comment: Seems you need to define what exactly is your desired allowed patterns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a less complex regex :

```
^\+?\d{2}(-?\d){8,9}$
```

This regex allows a `+` at the beginning of the phone number, then matches two digits, and after that, digits preceded (or not) by a `-`, for a total of 10 or 11 digits.

Now you can adapt it if the initial `+` is only for 11-digits phone numbers :

```
^\+?\d{3}(-?\d){9}|\d{2}(-?\d){8}$
```

My regex allow you to use `-` every digit.  If that's an issue, it can be changed :

```
^\+?\d{3}(-?\d{2}){4}|\d{2}(-?\d{2}){4}$
```

I think this last regex will answer your needs, and it's quite simple !

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Do you write these regexes yourself? Or do you use a tool?

I'd like to learn it :-)

Comment: @user2191227 : I wrote these myself, using http://www.regexr.com/ to check if the syntax is correct and test what it matches / doesn't match. It's a very good tool, to practice !

Answer (score 0):

When you figure out what patterns you actually want to allow and not allow. Then fill them out in this function and if the statement returns true you have your regex.

```
var regex = /^\+?\d{3}(-?\d{2}){4}|\d{2}(-?\d{2}){4}$/; //this is your regex, based on @Theox third answer

 //allowed patterns
['0612345678', '+31612345678', '+316-12345678', '06-12345678'].every(function(test) {
  return regex.exec(test) !== null;
}) &&
 //disallowed patterns, none right now
[].every(function(test) {
  return regex.exec(test) === null;
});
```